# What does this function do?

Tags: python

```
def fun1(a):

    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = a[i] * a[i]
    return a
```

Comment: Should this be tagged "homework" perhaps?

Comment: sadly tag `beginner` does not fully reflect quality of the question

Comment: please do not use the homework tag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: only three years passed. and still 13.7k questions to go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It takes an array as parameter and returns the same array with each member squared.

EDIT:

Since you modified your question from 'What does this function do' to 'What is some code to execute this function', here is an example:

```
def fun1(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = a[i] * a[i]
    return a

test1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
print 'Original list', test1
test2 = fun1(test1)
print 'Result', test2
print 'Original list', test1
```

The output will be:

```
Original list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Result [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
Original list [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Because the function modifies the list in place, test1 is also modified.

Comment: and it can also be written as:
 [item*item for item in a]

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that it actually modifies the variable that was passed to the function. If you apply it more than once to the same variable you will get a different result each time.

Answer (score 3):

It will go through your List and multiply each value by itself.

**Example**

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

After that function a would look like this:

```
a = [ 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36 ]
```

Comment: In Python a list uses square brackets

Answer (score 3):

It's a trivial function that could be replaced with the one-liner:

```
a = [x*x for x in a]
```

Comment: That probably just confuses him.

Comment: I suspect that for a beginner, this will be even more confusing.

Comment: I don't think it's confusing. (Simple) list comprehensions were not at all confusing for me as a Python beginner.

Comment: Also, as demonstrated by Andre's example, it's not exactly identical. `a = fun1(a)` is identical to `a = [x*x for x in a]` but `b = fun1(a)` is not the same as `b = [x*x for x in a]` (this should probably be considered a bug in `fun1` ).

Comment: Chris, I think you're taking my example as general when it wasn't meant to be. There's a reason why my example starts with `a =`.

Answer (score 2):

it multiplies each element of the array "a" with itself and stores the results back in the array.

Answer (score 2):

a is passed as a list , I assume.

It squares each element of the list and returns the list.

Answer (score 1):

It *squares* every element in the input array and returns the squared array.

So with `a = [1,2,3,4,5]`

result is: `[1,4,9,16,25]`